# WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL

Tags: mysql, wpdb

Here is the constructor for the wpdb class as found in the source code.
According to a google search this has been recently renamed from USE_EXT_MYSQL.
However I cannot find anywhere in the source code where either constant is defined.

```
function __construct( $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost ) {
    register_shutdown_function( array( $this, '__destruct' ) );

    if ( WP_DEBUG && WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
        $this->show_errors();

    /* Use ext/mysqli if it exists and:
     *  - WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL is defined as false, or
     *  - We are a development version of WordPress, or
     *  - We are running PHP 5.5 or greater, or
     *  - ext/mysql is not loaded.
     */
    if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_connect' ) ) {
        if ( defined( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL' ) ) {
            $this->use_mysqli = ! WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL;
        } elseif ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.5', '>=' ) || ! function_exists( 'mysql_connect' ) ) {
            $this->use_mysqli = true;
        } elseif ( false !== strpos( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '-' ) ) {
            $this->use_mysqli = true;
        }
    }
```

Can someone please explain to me what the code does and whether there has been
an omission somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constant is actually never defined in core code at all. You can define it yourself in `wp-config.php` configuration if you need to, but core doesn't *need* it defined for normal operation. It only exists for re–configuring into running untypical setup.

Answer (score 1):

Since [WordPress 3.9](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.9), WP uses MySQLi as the default connection method when:

- The MySQLi extension is installed on the webserver AND

  1. The WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL constant is set to false (in the *wp-config.php*) OR
  2. The webserver runs PHP version 5.5 or later OR
  3. The ext/mysql is not loaded

** Setting the WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL constant to true causes WordPress to use the MySQL extension instead of the MySQLi extension.